# Ubuntu 9.1 and dynamic disks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dynamic-disk

I bought my laptop with Win 7 pre-installed and I shrinked a partition and created a free unallocated space , but when I was installing ubuntu It called this space "unusable" . So I started reading a bit and found that My disk is a dynamic disk and that's different from the basic disk so It doesn't have primary or logical disks ( Am I right ?) . I still want to install ubuntu what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

- Install Ubuntu using [Wubi method](http://technofriends.in/2008/08/02/installing-ubuntu-on-windows-using-wubi/).
- [Virtualize](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox) Ubuntu
- [Convert the dynamic disc to basic disc](http://mypkb.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/how-to-non-destructively-convert-dynamic-disks-to-basic-disks/) and then try installing

If I were you, I'd probably go for virtualization method

Comment: I guess those are all the valid options , Can you till me which is a suitable virtualization software ?

Comment: @Ahmed you can use VirtualBox - I've linked a how-to article in my answer